# How do I test image loading when lazy-loading is used

Tags: testing, cypress

I am trying to verify the image properties inside of a slider. The strange thing is that my test works once and fails another time.

This is my code:

```
it('Verify image properties', () => {
        cy.visit('https://geschaeftskunden.telekom.de/mobilfunk')
        cy.get('button[id="consentAcceptAll"]').click()
        cy.get('#CM551318').find('.flickity-slider > [data-teaser-variant]').then( $handytoolbar =>{
            cy.wrap($handytoolbar).find('img').should('be.visible')
                .each(($img) =>{
                    expect($img[0].naturalWidth).to.be.greaterThan(0)
                    expect($img[0].naturalHeight).to.be.greaterThan(0) 
            })

    })
```

You can see my cypress test in the screenshot. Any ideas what I can do to make the test work more reliably?

[Cypress Test Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOD3y.png)

[Image Slider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jiBId.png)

Answer (score 6):

The key factor is your images load slowly (because of the size of them) and the way you currently test them with `expect($img[0].naturalWidth).to.be.greaterThan(0)` has no retry.

You can change that by using `.should()` instead of `expect()`.

Another factor is getting the image into view. It appear this site uses lazy loading for the images, so they only appear when the user scrolls to that place on the page.

That feature is worth testing, but to start I would side-step by making the page really large in the viewport, to avoid having to work out the scrolling.

Also there is horizontal scroll on the slider that only means 6 images are loaded at a time, although 12 `<img>` elements are placed on the page.

Therefore, as a first step I would limit the test to the first 6 images.

```js
cy.viewport(2500, 5000)
cy.visit('https://geschaeftskunden.telekom.de/mobilfunk')
cy.get('button[id="consentAcceptAll"]').click()
cy.get('#CM551318')
  .find('.flickity-slider')
  .find('img')
  .each(($img, index) => {
    if (index < 6) {
      cy.wrap($img).should('have.prop', 'naturalWidth').and('be.gt', 0)
    }
  })
```

[image]